# KeyEvent code for hiding software keyboard?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, keyevent, keycode

When a software keyboard is opened on my virtual device, the back button changes function to hide the keyboard when pressed - it does not stay 'KEYCODE_BACK' like it does whilst the keyboard is hidden.

Is this "hide" button still defined as a KeyEvent or do I need to go a different route in order to run an activity whenever it is pressed?

- Android Studio 3.0.1

  ```
  //setup i was hoping to use, but keycode changes whenever keyboard is shown//

  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
          if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
          {
              checkEmpty();
          }
          return false;
      }
  ```

Comment: "Is this "hide" button still defined as a KeyEvent" -- I don't think so. "do I need to go a different route in order to run an activity whenever it is pressed?" -- AFAIK, the system does not pass that event to the activity. It just collapses the input method editor (soft keyboard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by CommonsWare, "the system does not pass that event [back button while keyboard is displayed] to the activity. It just collapses the input method editor (soft keyboard)."

So no, it does not trigger a KeyEvent.